# Summarizing results obtained in different scenarios by different methods

Tags: experiment-design, simulation, descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics

I have generated different scenarios which depends on certain parameters $x_1, \dots, x_k$. I have evaluated each scenario with different methods. Summarizing, I have a value $S(m,x_1, \dots, x_k)$ depending on the method, $m$, and the parameters used to generate scenario.

What is a good practice to summarize the results obtained by each method?

I've been thinking about using a linear model to predict $S$ using the method $m$ and the average conditions $\bar{x}_1, \dots, \bar{x}_k$, and then comparing the results. Although it seems reasonable, do you think it is correct? Do you know about some alternative? Do you know about a reference I can use to justify the obtained predictions?